# Should the return value of cJSON_Print() be freed by the caller?

Tags: c, json, cjson

I am using the [cJSON library](http://cjson.sourceforge.net/) and I have a function as follows:

```
void printJsonObject(cJSON *item)
{
    char *json_string = cJSON_Print(item);
    printf("%s\n", json_string);
}
```

Will this function leak memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cJSON memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158734/cjson-memory-leak)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never used cJSON , but as per the function definition present in this [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjson/code/HEAD/tree/cJSON.c), it looks like

```
char *cJSON_Print(cJSON *item)  {return print_value(item,0,1);}
```

and

```
static char *print_value(cJSON *item,int depth,int fmt);
```

From `print_value()` function, the pointer returned is allocated by `cJSON_strdup()` [which is a modified version of the combination of `malloc()` and `memcpy()`] and it is returned to the caller.

As I see no method to track the allocation, IMO, the allocated memory needs to be `free()`d by the caller function. Otherwise, it will be a memory leak.

Comment: This was correct at the time, however the correct API is now `cJSON_free`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a memory leak.

Buffers returned by `cJSON_Print` must be freed by the caller. Please use the proper API (`cJSON_free`) rather than directly calling stdlib `free`.

See the cJSON maintainer's comment: https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/issues/5#issuecomment-298469697

---

I recommend:

```
void printJsonObject(cJSON *item)
{
    char *json_string = cJSON_Print(item);
    if (json_string) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", json_string);
        cJSON_free(json_string);
    }
}
```