# create json object using cJSON.h

Tags: c, json, cjson

I am trying to create JSON object like below but I am not able to add the second item in it e.g:

```
"CarType": "mercedes",
"carID": "merc123"
```

and also other items.

I want to create JSON like this:

```
{
  cars: [
    {
      "CarType": "BMW",
      "carID": "bmw123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "mercedes",
      "carID": "merc123"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "volvo",
      "carID": "vol123r"
    },
    {
      "CarType": "ford",
      "carID": "ford123"
    }
  ]
};
```

I have tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main (void){
    char field_name[32], value[32], *out;
    cJSON *root,*car;

    root  = cJSON_CreateObject();
    car=  cJSON_CreateArray();

    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "CarType", cJSON_CreateString("BMW"));
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "carID", cJSON_CreateString("bmw123"));
    cJSON_AddItemToArray(car, root);

    out = cJSON_Print(car);
    printf("%s\n",out);

    return 0;
}
```

My Output is something like this (indentation is exactly as showed here):

```
[{
        "CarType":  "BMW",
        "carID":    "bmw123"
    }]
```

Comment: and what is the question...?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in the first place, incl. elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/)

Comment: Edit your question to show us what you have tried and what the actual problem is.

Comment: And what is the problem/output?

Comment: Marcin Orlowski  - for your info i  am putting effort before asking the question & after posting it until i got the answer. and thanks for letting me know that this is not the tutorial site.by the way i got the answer .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code will show you how to use the cJSON functions like `cJSON_CreateObject()`, `cJSON_CreateArray()`, `cJSON_AddItemToObject()` and `cJSON_AddItemToArray()`.

You have to add the `cars` array to the `root` object. After that you have to create each `car` as object containing items which are the `CarType` and `carID`. Each `car` object has to be added to the `cars` array.

It it also very well documentated with examples [here at GitHub](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON).

**Edit #1:**

As @JonnySchubert pointed out, it's necessary to free allocated ressources. But it's enough to free the root node in this case, because adding an item to an array or object transfers it's ownership. In other words: freeing the root node will cause freeing all nodes under root also. From the GitHub ressource I linked above:

> For every value type there is a `cJSON_Create...` function that can be used to create an item of that type. All of these will allocate a `cJSON` struct that can later be deleted with `cJSON_Delete`. Note that you have to delete them at some point, otherwise you will get a memory leak. **Important:** If you have added an item to an array or an object already, you **mustn't** delete it with `cJSON_Delete`. Adding it to an array or object transfers its ownership so that when that array or object is deleted, it gets deleted as well.

**Edit #2:**

@lsalamon mentioned that you have to free the return value of cJSON_Print, see [here on SO for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394515/8051589) and [the documentation](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON#printing).

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main()
{
   char *out;
   cJSON *root, *cars, *car;

   /* create root node and array */
   root = cJSON_CreateObject();
   cars = cJSON_CreateArray();

   /* add cars array to root */
   cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "cars", cars);

   /* add 1st car to cars array */
   cJSON_AddItemToArray(cars, car = cJSON_CreateObject());
   cJSON_AddItemToObject(car, "CarType", cJSON_CreateString("BMW"));
   cJSON_AddItemToObject(car, "carID", cJSON_CreateString("bmw123"));

   /* add 2nd car to cars array */
   cJSON_AddItemToArray(cars, car = cJSON_CreateObject());
   cJSON_AddItemToObject(car, "CarType", cJSON_CreateString("mercedes"));
   cJSON_AddItemToObject(car, "carID", cJSON_CreateString("mercedes123"));

   /* print everything */
   out = cJSON_Print(root);
   printf("%s\n", out);
   free(out);

   /* free all objects under root and root itself */
   cJSON_Delete(root)

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "cars": [{
            "CarType":  "BMW",
            "carID":    "bmw123"
        }, {
            "CarType":  "mercedes",
            "carID":    "mercedes123"
        }]
}
```

This code just add 2 cars to show the usage. In your real application you should do that with C arrays and a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your time & effort.

Comment: Never forget to free dynamic memory at the end by calling cJSON_Delete(root) and to free the string allocated by cJSON.

Comment: Calling free (out) is required or memory leak will occur.

Answer (score 1):

If the json string is fixed you could simply use `cJSON_Parse` function, to do that you need to have the `char*` to it  :

```
   const char* const json_string = 
"{ \
  \"cars\": [\
    {\
      \"CarType\": \"BMW\",\
      \"carID\": \"bmw123\"\
    },\
    {\
      \"CarType\": \"mercedes\",\
      \"carID\": \"merc123\"\
    },\
    {\
      \"CarType\": \"volvo\",\
      \"carID\": \"vol123r\"\
    },\
    {\
      \"CarType\": \"ford\",\
      \"carID\": \"ford123\"\
    }\
  ]\
}\
";

   cJSON * root = cJSON_Parse(json_string);  /* Play with root */

   //char *rendered = cJSON_Print(root);
```

Updated as per request , **when input array is not fixed**:

```
   const char* const carType[] ={"BMW", "Mercides", "Audi", "Farari"}; 
   const char* const carID[]  ={"bmw11", "m22", "a33", "f44"} ;

   size_t max_size = 4;
   cJSON *root,*car;

   root  = cJSON_CreateObject();
   car=  cJSON_CreateArray();

   for( size_t i = 0; i < max_size; ++i )
   {
      cJSON* item  = cJSON_CreateObject(); 
      cJSON_AddItemToObject(item, "CarType", cJSON_CreateString( carType[i] ));
      cJSON_AddItemToObject(item, "carID", cJSON_CreateString(carID[i]));

      cJSON_AddItemToArray(car, item);
   }


   cJSON_AddItemToObject( root, "cars", car );
```

Comment: it is not Fixed it will come from some string array.

Comment: string carType[]={"BMW", "Mercides", "Audi", "Farari"};
string carID[]={"bmw11", "m22", "a33", "f44"};

Comment: @Abhishek You need to mention this in your post, we don't have psychic  ability to read people mind.

Comment: @Abhishek Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution i got -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main (void){
    char field_name[32], value[32], *out;
    cJSON *root,*car;

    root  = cJSON_CreateObject();
    car=  cJSON_CreateArray();


    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "CarType", cJSON_CreateString("BMW"));
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "carID", cJSON_CreateString("bmws123"));
    cJSON_AddItemToArray(car, root);

    root=NULL;
    root  = cJSON_CreateObject();

    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "CarType", cJSON_CreateString("Mercedies"));
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "carID", cJSON_CreateString("mer123"));
    cJSON_AddItemToArray(car, root);



    out = cJSON_Print(car);
    printf("%s\n",out);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes would work but names are wrong in usage here as you using `root` **not** as root object. Further you have just an array `car` without a root object.