# Chances of memory leak in cJSON_Print in CPP

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, cjson

I have seen multiple documentation citing that use of cJSON_Print like the below example needs to be accompanied with a call for free(), else it will cause a memory leak.

```
char* char_json = cJSON_Print(jsonvar)
```

Will I get a memory leak issue if I use it like this for printing or logging?

```
fprintf(stderr, "Value of JSON is %s", cJSON_Print(jsonvar));
```

Is there a chance of a memory leak here?
Also, is this a good practice? Using one single char ptr to assign and store multiple JSON Print outputs.

```
char* one_var_for_all_json;
one_var_for_all_json = cJSON_Print(jsonvar_one);
//use the value in char array
one_var_for_all_json = cJSON_Print(jsonvar_two);
//use the new value
//finally free it with
free(one_var_for_all_json);
```

The answers in this [Should the return value of cJSON_Print() be freed by the caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394364/should-the-return-value-of-cjson-print-be-freed-by-the-caller) only answer scenarios where the output of cJSON is allocated to a variable in that scope. I have doubts when it's output is directly passed to something like a printf statement. Also my second doubt isn't answered in the accused duplicate.

Comment: Google is your friend!

Comment: ... And match every call to `cJSON_Print` with a call to `cJSON_free`, yes, maybe make yourself a little RAII wrapper class (or, better, use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter).